# Ejecutar un método de un modelo y a su vez ejecutar un evento en Javascript desde un boton (Odoo 10)

Tags: javascript

Estoy usando Odoo 10, y he creado un modelo que hereda de hr_employee. En el modelo que creé, agregé un botón que ejecuta un action window. En el modelo definí un método que será ejecutado desde un botón en el action, este método descargá una imágen captcha de una página y necesito que una vez descargada la imágen esta se muestre dentro del action.

Como puedo hacer todo esto desde javascript?

Vista del action:

```
    <record id="captcha_view" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">captcha.view</field>
        <field name="model">captcha.window</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form>
                <group name="group_top">
                    <group name="group_left">
                        <field name="captcha_code"/>
                        <button name="load_captcha" string="Cargar código"
                               type="object" class="oe_highlight load_captcha" icon="fa-refresh"/>
                    </group>
                    <group name="group_right">
                        <!-- Aqui quiero la imagen captcha -->
                    </group>
                </group>
                <footer>
                    <button name="main" string="Actualizar" type="object" class="oe_highlight"/>
                </footer>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
</data>
```